# How to minimize build server project specific configuration?

Tags: maven, jenkins, build-process, travis-ci

My case is about having **too much complex project configuration logic inside Jenkins jobs definition** and in time this becoming harder and hard to deal with. This also prevents you from easily execute build jobs under other build/CI tools.

If those projects would be Java based anyone would probably tell me to use maven as I could put most of the things inside the pom.xml files and have them with the project. Still, in my case is more about C/C++ or even .NET projects for which the all the build scripts are usually in bash (cygwin being a dependency on Windows).

I do know that theoretically I could code the parts that are now inside jenkins job configuration in those bash files but this would clearly require significant effort and would be really hard to tune them to allow to enable and disable different steps based on external conditions.

So, what I am trying here is to achieve a high level of independency regarding the build system, so if I want I could switch it in the long future.

What would you recommend as a solution for that? Obviously I need something that can be used multiplatform and not tightened to a specific build system.

**Does it make sense to use maven for that, even if those projects are not Java ones?** Personally I am not a big fan of XML configuration files, YAML, JSON and INI being seen as more friendly.

What kind of extra logic existing in Jenkins configuration are we talking about?
One would deployment, as I want to be able to deploy to Nexus or similar repositories, executing tests, code coverage and maybe posting the results somewhere.

As a sidenote, looking at Travis configuration files makes me wonder why Jenkins didn't go for such approach.

Comment: Pick any build tool. Not only maven - this is very Java tool. Try gradle, rake, make etc. :)

Comment: Thanks @DracoAter - we already use `make` in some of the projects but clearly there are no such things as deployment plugins for make. I had some limited (good) experience with `rake` but Ruby is not loved so much around here, a `Python` solution would clearly be easier to embrace as is very popular inside the company and already listed as a dependency (as opposed to Ruby)

Answer (score 1):

Look at Groovy. Jenkins allows direct Groovy code manipulating almost everything. A Groovy script could be used to take care of everything from project specific configuration, and it could even be checked in together with the source code. Then in the Jenkins job, you just have a single build step to call the Groovy script.

The above suggestion, however, is very Jenkins dependent.

Another possibility is an Ant script. The **[AntExec](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/AntExec+plugin)** plugin allows to execute Ant script, along with ant-contrib if needed, using the same tools installation process that the rest of Jenkins use. Therefore, you don't need to worry about Ant being installed on the node: Jenkins will take care of it on demand.

The benefits of the Ant script is that it's not tied to Java concepts as Maven is, it's cross platform (Windows and Linux), and just like the Groovy script example above, it can be checked in along with the rest of the source code.